# Two Questions about ORMs and Database cleaning using the transaction strategy

Tags: ruby, orm, db2, database-cleaner

I am writing proof of concept tests using an existing Cucumber and Ruby suite. The corporation I am doing this for has a stack that includes Java and DB2 among other things.

Currently the tests that use the database degrade our test database, and for many reasons I can't wipe the database away and replace it with an imaged version.

I am interested in the idea of using a transaction strategy to clean the database, and I am considering the database_cleaner gem.

It seems as if database_cleaner needs an ORM to work with. I do not have access to the schema at this point, and ActiveRecord can't access what it needs with my credentials.

Two questions:

1. Do ORMs always need access to the schema?
2. Do you always need an ORM to clean a database using the transaction strategy?

Also a bonus if anybody knows gems that are available that work with ruby 1.8.7 (no jRuby yet), windows, DB2, etc.

Comment: Which ORMs have you looked at? Sequel, DataMapper and Active Record are the big three for Ruby. They should be OS agnostic, as they're pure Ruby. Whether they can connect or run is more tied to the drivers they use and whether those compile on your system.

Comment: Would an in memory db work for your tests instead of using a real db2 database? Of course you need to create your own test data then.

Comment: @theTinMan I've tried Sequel and Active Record. Sequel seemed like it was trying to use Active Record, too, under the hood. I thought that I should maybe just be using Active Record...

Comment: @PeterSchuetze management wants to test the behavior of the real database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do ORMs always need access to the schema?

Schema? As in a text dump of the database's tables and relational fields and indexes? No. Do they need to be able to read the database's house-keeping data that describes the tables and their relationships? Yes. That's how they build models.

1. Do you always need an ORM to clean a database using the transaction strategy?

Heck no. You can go all old-school on it and write it in the SQL for that particular DBM, assuming it supports transactions. An ORM just makes it more portable and usually a lot easier to write because you're relying on it to know how to generate the appropriate SQL.

I like [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html) for my ORM because I can use raw SQL if I insist otherwise I can use it with "datasets" or with full models and relational information about them. Plus, it generates very nice SQL, which I can easily check. I highly recommend it.

[Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) comes with Rails and is probably the most used ORM with Ruby as a result. That doesn't mean it's the best, which is a matter of opinion, but it is common. Active Record isn't isolated to Rails use; You can use it with regular Ruby apps too, though that's a little bit like going against the flow. I used it in the past to tie Ruby to a legacy database, without the Rails layer, and it worked fine.

I haven't used [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) in a while, but it seemed nice when I was using it, and I'd recommend looking at it. Everyone's brain assimilates data differently and we like different APIs, hence variety in our ORMs, so it might flow into your brain where the others don't go willingly.

Comment: Thanks, Tin man, I really think I could try Sequel again. Have you used it with DB2 by any chance?

Comment: I haven't used it with DB2 but that's because we don't use DB2 in house. [DB2 is supported](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/DB2.html) though. I've used it to hit Sybase and MSSQL via TinyTDS and ODBC from Linux. Getting the drivers working was the hard part but using Sequel worked nicely.